# exosip always answer twice when receive invite event

Tags: sip

I'm new in sip and use exosip to develop a sip gateway.
I found my gate way is always send answer twice, but the log in my program just print once.
I don't know what happened and how to fix this problem.

[image: duplicate answer]

---

UPDATE:
I update my version to 5.2.0, but the problem still exists.
Also, I found there exists duplicated RTP connections:
[image: duplicated RTP connection]

The question most bothers me is that audio packets are duplicated, which makes high packet loss rate:
[image: packet loss]

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.1.2, there was a major rewrite of DNS, UDP, TCP and TLS management. The rewrite was required to maximize performance and to reach the same results with *select* and *epoll* implementations. Those changes introduced issues resolved in incremental steps and 3 versions were published in a row: exosip **5.1.2**, **5.1.3** and finally **5.2.0**

Your issue was fixed only in **5.2.0** with this ChangeLog line:

```
* fix duplicate packets for TCP and TLS when several outgoing NICT are happening at the same time [since 5.1.2]
```

The git fix is this one:

https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/exosip.git/commit/?id=1fdc54ed38eaf5155f5702240586c472f2cc73d4

You can read the full [ChangeLog here](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/exosip.git/tree/ChangeLog) for details.

There as been 3 commits since **5.2.0** in the git which may be nice to have. [access git here](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/exosip.git)

Make sure you also use latest osip **5.2.0** [or access git here](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/osip.git). There was only one additionnal commit which is also interesting.

**NOTE:** In my own tests: I have seen only retransmission of *REQUESTs*, but I would not be surprised if the bug was also affecting *ANSWERS*? If you use already the latest version, please write me a mail.

Comment: I have checked my version which was 5.1.1 and update to 5.2.0. However, it does't works. Furthermore, I found there also exists dumplicated RTP connections.

Comment: osip/exosip is not implementing RTP. If you have duplicate for all packets, or close to all packets. Then, it may just be wireshark. I've seen this before.